# Filtering out an array depending on the value of object inside it

Tags: reactjs

I have a array

```
    [
      {
       email: "test@gmail.com"
       loginLink: "http://localhost:3000/signup?q=f1aea1ff-c833-4e7b-8608-a1f51a9da104"
       name: "Pulkit (Creator)"
       roles: {hr: false, manager: true, admin: true}
      
      },  {and similar more values}
```

Now i am already sorting out values according to the name and email by the following way

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setOnScreenUsers(
      users.filter((user) => {
        if (userFilterQ === "") {
          return user;
        } else if (
          user.user.name.toLowerCase().includes(userFilterQ.toLowerCase()) ||
          user.user.email.toLowerCase().includes(userFilterQ.toLowerCase())
        ) {
          return user;
        } else {
          return "";
        }
      })
    );
  }, [userFilterQ, users]);
```

**This thing is working properly. Now let say the user wants to get only those array who have role of hr or manager (one at a time). How can this be acheived**

PS:I am storing the filtered array in another array to render

Let me know if you need any extra info

Comment: What do you mean by one at a time?

Comment: User cannot filter out hr or manager together. It's would be either manager or hr

Comment: I think you don't quite understand how `array.prototype.filter` works. You return true/truthy if you want to include that element in the result filtered array, and false/falsey if you want to omit it from the result. Are you asking how to filter by multiple properties of an object? I.e. in addition to filtering by `name` you want to also filter by `role`?

Comment: Yup, I want to filter by role in addition to name

Comment: Do you mind providing an example how the role filtering should be applied? Is it a static check that the role must be either 'hr' or 'manager' or is this something the UI is providing, similar to the `userFilterQ` for name?

Comment: The array contains the details of the user which are rendered using the map function. Now the user has a dropdown option which allows him to select either hr or manager or admin. Now if the user clicks on hr the value is stored and now array should have only those index that have user.user.role.hr = true

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misunderstanding of how the [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method works. In the callback function you're supposed to return a boolean value (false, to remove the item from the filtered array)

What you're trying to do just involves adding another conditional to your callback function.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setOnScreenUsers(
        users.filter((user) => {
            if (serFilterQ === "") {
                return true;
            }

            const lowercaseFilterQ = userFilterQ.toLowerCase();
            if (
                user.user.name.toLowerCase().includes(lowercaseFilterQ) ||
                user.user.email.toLowerCase().includes(lowercaseFilterQ) ||
                // Change the line below to whatever type of role you'd like
                user.user.roles.hr
            ) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        })
    );
}, [userFilterQ, users]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If applying a filter for the `role` property then you can simply add that as an additional conditional test.

You can also simplify the logic a bit. If filter values are falsey, just return `true` so all elements are filtered through to result array. If any filter query values are truthy then return the boolean expression instead.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setOnScreenUsers(
    users.filter((user) => {
      if (!userFilterQ && !roleFilterQ) return true;

      const filterValue = userFilterQ.toLowerCase();
      return (
        user.user.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
        user.user.email.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
        user.user.role[roleFilterQ] // roleFilterQ one of "hr", "manager", "admin"
      );
    })
  );
}, [userFilterQ, users]);
```

Let us know if you are filtering `role` by multiple values, the logic would need a slight tweak.

Comment: But whether the user has the access to the role or not depends on the boolean true or false. Even if the user do not has access to the role, the key would still persists. Moreover user.user.role is a object

Comment: @PulkitGupta That's ok, even if the keys didn't exist, `undefined` is a falsey value so the condition would still be evaluated correctly. It is quite clear and understood that `user.user.role` is an object from your example snippet.

Comment: Ohk it's my lack of knowledge sorry. But still it does not work I don't know whether I am applying it wrong, or something else

Comment: @PulkitGupta Can you create a simple, *running* codesandbox with your code that we can look at. It's likely just a simple tweak to match the condition test to the data from the dropdown. Just enough to reproduce some users to filter and the UI to select the filters should be sufficient.

Comment: I was working on it and got the error, had to format this a bit. Thanks a lot!!